# Bloc type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: json, flutter, bloc

Good day!
Please help me to figure out this error in little testing app.

model/people:

```
class People extends Equatable {
  final int charId;
 });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        charId,
      ];

  static People fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return People(
      charId: json['char_id'],
      );
  }
}
```

APIClient:

```
class APIClient {
  static const baseUrl = '******';
  final http.Client httpClient;

  APIClient({
    required this.httpClient,
  }) : assert(httpClient != null);

  Future<People> fetchPeopleAPI(int id) async {
    final mainUrl = '***';

    final peopleResponse = await this.httpClient.get(Uri.parse(mainUrl));

    if (peopleResponse.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('error getting people with id');
    }
    final peopleJson = jsonDecode(peopleResponse.body);
    return People.fromJson(peopleJson);
  }
}
```

Bloc:

```
class PeopleBloc extends Bloc<PeopleEvent, PeopleState> {
  final PeopleRepo peopleRepo;

  PeopleBloc({
    required this.peopleRepo,
  })   : assert(peopleRepo != null),
        super(PeopleInitialState());

  @override
  Stream<PeopleState> mapEventToState(
    PeopleEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is PeopleRequestedEvent) {
      yield PeopleLoadInProgressState();
      try {
        final People people = await peopleRepo.getPeople(event.id);
        yield PeopleLoadSuccessState(people: people);
      } catch (e) {
        print("error : $e");
        yield PeopleLoadFailureState();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Exactly in the bloc.dart I get this exception with text " **error : type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'**". Help to find mistake, please.

Comment: What line does it tell you the error is on?

Comment: I have a message via print("error: $e") in mapEventToState

Comment: If I use not char_id, but String name, commenting the char_id field I get a message again. error : type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Comment: maybe the reason in api? cause when I use another public API there is no any mistake

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be this part:

```
static People fromJson(dynamic json) {
  return People(
    charId: json['char_id'],
    );
}
```

Since `json` parameter is dynamic, the `json['char_id']` value is dynamic as well. Assuming your API returns an integer as `char_id`, you can parse it like:

```
static People fromJson(dynamic json) {
  return People(
    charId: json['char_id'] as int,
    );
}
```

Comment: if it doesn't work maybe look into `int.parse(yourString)`?

Comment: Hmmm... In which place?

Answer (score 0):

okay, my mistake. I get not single json, but array. I put and index and everything become good ))

```
final peopleJson = jsonDecode(peopleResponse.body);
return People.fromJson(peopleJson[0]);
```